# Conditionally check value from context and then navigate after login in the same function call in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, I'm using the `context API` to set the user data or the errors returned by the API request:

```
// context
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState("")
const [error, setError] = useState("")

async function login(credentials) {
    setError("")
    try {
        ...API request
        const data = await response.json()
        if(data.success) {
            setCurrentUser(data)
        } else {
            setError(data.error)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        setError("Something went wrong. Please try again.")
    }
}

<AuthContext.Provider value={login, currentUser, error}>
    {children}
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

Then in my component:

```
//component
const { login, currentUser, error } = useContext(AuthContext)

const onSubmit = async (credentials) => {
    setLoading(true)
    await login(credentials)
    resetForm({})
    setLoading(false)
    !error && navigate("/")
}

return (
    ...
)
```

Now the `onSubmit` function allows the user to `navigate` to `/` even if there is an `error` set by the `context` - this is because (I think) the `error` is still `null` by the time it's checked and the component doesn't get the chance to rerender to get the newest value.

What would be the best approach to avoid this behavior? Should I handle the error locally in the component and not the `context`? If yes, what would be the best way to do so in my scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick solution

Of course, there are other ways of doing this, but the one that wouldn't change your current structure much is to change the `onSubmit` function so you don't do the redirection there:

```
const onSubmit = async (credentials) => {
    setLoading(true)
    await login(credentials)
    resetForm({})
    setLoading(false)
}
```

Create an `useEffect` that would do the redirection, but based on whether there is a user or not:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(currentUser){
    navigate("/")
  }
},[currentUser])
```

And yes, when you are calling `!error && navigate("/")`, there is no re-render yet, and therefore `error` is still equal to `""`, which is why the redirection is happening right away.

## Another way

Assuming that the login process is handled in one place (which is the case in most scenarios), there is no need to have `login` function and `error` state as part of the context. The context should export just `setCurrentUser` and `currentUser`.

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={currentUser, setCurrentUser}>
    {children}
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

The login and errors related to logging would be handled inside the login page, and it would call `setCurrentUser` to update the context for other components:

```
const {currentUser, setCurrentUser} =  useContext(AuthContext)
```

And you would use the same `useEffect` as above to make redirection when there is `currentUser`.